# Link an Alexa Skill to a specific Lambda alias

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'd like to make use of AWS Lambda's [versioning and aliases](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-aliases.html) for managing code which is linked to an Alexa Skill.

Therefore, I have two aliases `PROD` and `UAT` (pretty much as described in the [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/aliases-intro.html)).

However - If I try to configure the ARN of one of my aliases (e.g. `arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:1234567:function:Alexa-Skill:PROD`) to be the endpoint for an Alexa skill in the Amazon Developer Console I get the following error:

`Error: Please make sure that "Alexa Skills Kit" is selected for the event source type of arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:1234567:function:Alexa-Skill:PROD`

The unqualified ARN (i.e. `arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:1234567:function:Alexa-Skill`) works fine.

Is this a known limitation of the integration between Alexa Skills Kit and Lambda?

Comment: Have you added Alexa as a trigger for your alias?

Comment: Agree with the above comment. The Alexa Skills Kit trigger type may not be associated with your PROD alias; this can happen when you create a new alias or version.  Double check that and re-apply it if it is missing.

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni - you are quite right: I'd assumed that the triggers for the unqualified function also get applied to the Alias, but they don't.  I added the trigger in the configuration and it works now.  If you add this as an answer I'm happy to accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: @bunnmatt great! Ive added my answer.

Comment: A good source of info for this question: https://github.com/rgraciano/echo-sonos/issues/138

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to add the Alexa Skill as the trigger for the Lambda function alias for this to work.